# iTerm2/Oh My Zsh: How to change preview text font color?

Tags: oh-my-zsh, iterm

Simple questions, possibly more difficult answers...when I begin to type a command I have a preview/auto completion. I'm wondering how I can change the font color (too dark). I included screenshot for context

[image]

Comment: Which plugin is used for auto-completion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually it turned out this was an "oh my zshell" settings, so all I needed to do was export the `ZSH_AUTOSUGGEST_HIGHLIGHT_STYLE` within the `.zshrc` like so:

**`export ZSH_AUTOSUGGEST_HIGHLIGHT_STYLE="fg=100"`**

---

> *This brightened up the suggestion nicely so that I could actually read it:*

[image]

Comment: The `fg=100` did not work for me. I settled down on `fg=50`. Feel free to try variations and use what's required. Good find though!

Comment: `fg=100` and `fg=50` didn't do anything. Only values in the range `0-7` changed the color of the autocomplete text for me. The opacity or shading of the original color didn't change for me. This still worked for me since having a different autocomplete color is actually better than what I was originally looking for (just lowering the brightness of the text)

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust the theme colors in the Settings options for iTerm.

[image]